# Issues with processing PayPal Payment

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

We are using the secure token method to process credit card payments with PayPal hosted pages. We generate the secure token by providing the required information

```
[TRXTYPE=S, AMT=xxx, TENDER=C, ORDERID=xxxxxxxxxxxx, CURRENCY=USD, CREATESECURETOKEN=Y, SECURETOKENID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, PARTNER=Paypal, VENDOR=xxxxxx, USER=xxxxxx, PWD=xxxxxx]
```

We get the success result as follows:

```
{"RESULT"=>"0", "SECURETOKEN"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "SECURETOKENID"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "RESPMSG"=>"Approved"}
```

We then send this back to PayPal where the user can choose to pay with credit card and or PayPal.

When someone pays with credit card, all is fine, when someone chooses to pay using "PayPal" it asks user for PayPal credentials and once provided it shows another screen to accept the charges. Once the user accepts, we get the following error message:

```
 {"TYPE":"S","RESPMSG":"Original transaction ID not found: xxxxxxxxxxxx","TAX":"0.00","PNREF":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","TENDER":"P","AVSDATA":"XXN","METHOD":"P","SECURETOKEN":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","AMT":"1.00","SECURETOKENID":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","TRANSTIME":"2014-01-02 06:09:02","ORDERID":"xxxxxxxx36U1","RESULT":"19","DUPLICATE":"2","TRXTYPE":"S","action":"create","controller":"payment_notifications"}
```

The help I got from PayPal folks says "Looking at the logs it seems like the transaction was declined with the result code 19 which means that the transaction ID you entered for this transaction is not valid. When searched for the original transaction, I could not find any. So, it seems like the original transaction is not valid. Provide an valid original transaction ID and it should go through fine."

However nowhere in their documentation do they suggest to send this "transaction ID" variable and without it we have been processing Credit Card payments just fine.

My question:

What do i need to change in my process that I can accept Credit Card and PayPal payments?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was on PayPal side and they have yet to come back to us with an answer. Once thing which they do not openly advertise is that they have the ability to remove the Pay with PayPal button form the hosted pages so if someone else runs across the same issue they should ask PayPal to remove the Pay with PayPal button from their end, made sure to confirm that you are not disabling the service from express checkout just hiding the button.